# Use javascript to remove characters from a string based on a whitelist

Tags: javascript, regex, whitelist

I can't seem to find the answer to this.  I would like a generic function that allows me to remove all characters from a string that do not exist in a whitelist of characters.

```
var validChars = "0123456789%-"
var stringToTest = "The result is -2,003% of the total"
```

I'd like a function that would produce the result: -2,003%

Thanks for any help.
AD

Comment: ',' is not in white list... then how can you get -2,...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"I would like a generic function"*

OK, like this:

```
function removeChars(validChars, inputString) {
    var regex = new RegExp('[^' + validChars + ']', 'g');
    return inputString.replace(regex, '');
}

var newString = removeChars('01234567890%-', "The result is -2,003% of the total");
```

The `new RegExp()` part creates (for your particular input) a regex like this:

```
/[^01234567890%-]/g
```

Note that for this to work the way you intend a hyphen in the list of valid characters would need to be last in the list - you could add some extra code to test for this and move it. Also if the white list contained other characters that have special meaning to regular expressions (e.g., `]`) you'd have to escape them. I leave such details as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/):

```
"The result is -2,003% of the total".match(/[\d,%\-]+/)[0]; //=> -2,003%
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var regexp = new RegExp("[^" + validChars + "]", "g");
console.log(stringToTest.replace(regexp, ""));
```

Beware of `validChars` containing user input; in that case it should be properly escaped.